# How to edit .htaccess to remove .php

Tags: php, .htaccess

All of my pages end in .php, I need these pages to still be able to run PHP even though the extension has changed in the url bar. I want a page like

```
website.com/page.php
```

To

```
website.com/page
```

I have looked at half a dozen work arounds to this problem but none of them seem to work. Here are some examples.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L, QSA]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule \/([^\/]+)\/$ $1.php

# once per htaccess file
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_]+)/?$ /$1.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/shopName1.php$
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_]+).php$ /$1/ [R]
RewriteRule ^shops/shopName1/?$ /shopName1.php
RewriteRule ^shopName1.php$ /shops/shopName1/ [R]
```

Comment: Your question answer are on here..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Hide the .php Extension

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond /%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]+)/$ /$1.php
```

#### Explanation How this work

**Ans.** This rule will match *url.com/path/* and check, if *url.com/path.php* exists. If file exists then process ahead to rewrite rule apply.

Currently I used this rule Work perfect, Hope this help you!

---

***Updated***

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

in the above code the **-d** define for Directory and **-f** for Regular File.

This rule will same as above but its support ***Alphanumeric URL***. 
The above code is Tested and Work Fine with my server files.

***Example:*** If your filename is *"www.url.com/path1.php"* then your may access this file directly with *"www.url.com/path1"*.

Comment: +1 for making sure that the filename can (nearly) only be alphanumeric, as opposed to "Try This"

Comment: @AustinBurk thank you for your comment but check 3rd line rules a-zA-Z0-9 so its work not only alphabetic but also numeric url work fine. unfortunately i'm not try this in my existing url so i'm not give you surety.

Comment: @AlexPelletier thank you for testing numberic url not work. alphanumeric work great. oky i will create regexp for supporting numeric and alphabetic both are work.

Comment: all of my domains alphanumeric though? I will test again. Tested and i get my 404 page

Comment: @user1153551 What I meant as 'nearly alphanumeric' was that it include hyphens as well as a-z,A-z, and 0-9. Again, regex is not my forte, I'm probably wrong

Answer (score 2):

try this

`RewriteEngine On`

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`

`RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]`

Comment: Care to explain to OP _what_ this will do?

Comment: This does work, but I would love to see how this work?

Comment: It takes the directory name as an argument
/example
and simply tries to run a PHP file with that name. 
example.php
I feel like this could lead to to directory traversal, that regex may match any name (take that with a grain of salt, regex isn't my forte.) . What about "http://www.example.com/ls ~ && index"?

Comment: if `example.com/sample` is entered it searches for `example.com/sample.php` (it is case insensitive). If a folder exist in that directory is called `example2`, avoid naming a file `example2.php`, else if `example.com/example2` is entered, it will fetch `example.com/example2/`

Comment: @AlexPelletier if it solves your problem, mark it as your answer

Answer (score 0):

Just make a directory called page and rename page.php as index.php and put in in /page. If you need dynamic directories (like /product5 runs details.php?productid=5), *then* an .htaccess solution would be useful.